# How to reference control names dynamically in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have the following code in an MS Access Form object.

```
Private Sub UpdatePMText(sLang As String)
'Used to pass both Mandate and Language Info to called Sub that will execute the queries
Dim iMandate As Integer

'Check if there is text in the box.
If Me.Controls("txtInput_PM_" & sLang & "_DRAFT") = Null Or Me.Controls("txtInput_PM_" & sLang & "_DRAFT") = "" Then
    MsgBox ("There is no text in the " & sLang & " DRAFT Field." & vbNewLine & "The operation will not be executed.")
    Exit Sub
End If

iMandate = Me.txtMandateID
Call modUpdateText.macro_PMText(iMandate, sLang)

End Sub
```

If I refer to the Controls directly and simply type out the names of the forms, for example `txtInput_PM_EN_DRAFT` then the code works as intended.

The error message I get is that Access can't find the "Field" I'm referring to when I am on the first `IF` statement line. I have tried changing the `.Controls` to `.Fields` but that didn't work either.

I do not want to repeat the same code for every language I need to run. How do I reference control names dynamically in MS Access? What am I missing?

Comment: What is `txtInput_PM_EN_DRAFT`?  Is it a form or a control?  If that is the name of a form which is contained in a subform control, you need to use the name of the control ... which can be different than the name of the form it contains.

Comment: It is the name of the control that is directly on the form. There are no subforms. However, it is inside a tab control form, if that makes a difference.

Comment: It seems Access believes the form does not contain a control named `txtInput_PM_EN_DRAF‌​T`.  I suggest you the examine names of the controls which Access thinks the form contains.  With your form open in form view, try this as a single line in the Immediate window: `for each ctl in Forms!YourFormNameHere.Controls : ? ctl.name : next`

Comment: Later you will need to alter your code because nothing is ever equal to Null, not even another Null.  But that is not the cause of the problem you're facing right now.

Comment: Can you please give an example of what can be value of sLang and few of the names of the controls on your form. Make sure the string "txtInput_PM_" & sLang & "_DRAFT" makes a control name that is exactly there on the form, control names are not case sensitive which please note. So I guess the control names could be txtInput_PM_EN_DRAFT. To handle this situation if the control does not exists on the form, @dbmitch had suggested error handling which will pop-up message of such control does not exists.

Comment: @HansUp You were right that there was a spelling mistake in one of the forms. I also changed the NULL issue. THank you for you help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to add some basic troubleshooting. The answer is probably simpler than you think. It's likely you're just trying to lookup a textbox with mispelled name or it's failing on the Null comparison (as suggested by @HansUp)

I would try modifying your basic sub and testing it with this subroutine. As long as your code is in your current form and you're not referencing a subform your method will work.

```
Private Sub UpdatePMText(sLang As String)

    Const ERR_MISSING_CONTROL   As Long = 2465

On Error GoTo Err_UpdatePMText
    Dim sTextBox    As String

    sTextBox = "txtInput_PM_" & sLang & "_DRAFT"

    'Check if there is text in the box.
    If Nz(Me.Controls(sTextBox).Value, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox ("There is no text in the " & sLang & " DRAFT Field." & vbNewLine & "The operation will not be executed.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Exit Sub

Err_UpdatePMText:
    If Err.Number = ERR_MISSING_CONTROL Then
        MsgBox "Error: No Such Textbox: " & sTextBox
    Else
        MsgBox "Error Looking Up Textbox: """ & sTextBox & """" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I used your code with error handling. Worked perfectly after I also changed the naming issue. Thank you for your help as well!